# Changing window.navigator within puppeteer to bypass antibot system

Tags: selenium, puppeteer, detection

I'm trying to make my online bot undetectable. I read number of articles how to do it and I took all tips together and used them. One of them is to change `window.navigator.webdriver`.

I managed to change `window.navigator.webdriver` within puppeteer by this code:

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
        get: () => undefined
    });
});
```

I'm bypassing [this](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html) test just fine:

[image]

However [this](https://antoinevastel.com/bots/) test is still laughing at me somehow:

[image]

Why WEBDRIVER is inconsistent?

Comment: Try `delete window.navigator.webdriver` and see if it helps

Comment: It doesn't help, to be honest it's even worse and that's because `window.navigator` is read-only and `delete` will not even delete this object. That's why I'm using `Object.defineProperty` to overwrite it. When I removed `Object.defineProperty` and instead added `delete window.navigator.webdriver;` then when I open console in puppeteer chromedriver and write in console `window.navigator.webdriver` it's giving me true. Therefore test obviously failed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this,

First, remove the definition, it will not work if you define and delete from prototype.

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', ()=>{}) // <-- delete this part
```

Replace your code with this one.

```
delete navigator.__proto__.webdriver;
```

Result:
[image]

### Why does it work?

Removing directly just remove the instance of the object rather than the actual definition. The getter and setter is still there, so browser can find it.

[image]

However if you remove from the actual prototype, it will not exist at all in any instance anymore.

[image]

### Additional Tips

You mentioned you want to make your app undetectable, there are many plugins which achieve the same, for example this package called [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) includes some cool anti-bot detection techniques. *Sometimes* it's better to just reuse some packages than to re-create a solution over and over again.

PS: I might be wrong above the above explanation, feel free to guide me so I can improve the answer.

Comment: That's very weird but it doesn't work in my environment: https://i.imgur.com/6RnZgD1.png Could you share your project on github/bitbucket so I can match differences?

Comment: It will work, remove the define webdriver section above.

Comment: Right so that was because I was redefining navigator object multiple times.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Big thanks about "Additional Tips" I didn't know about this package existence.

Comment: Also upped for `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`!